# Pyplot graph doesn't plot to tkinter window

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class graphPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page")
        label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

             
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.a = plt.subplot2grid((6,4), (0,0), rowspan = 5, colspan = 4)
        self.a.plot([1,2,3,4,5], [10,20,30,40,50], "#00A3E0", label = "high")
        
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
  

f = plt.figure()

class stock(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        container = tk.Frame()
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(index=0, weight=1)         
        
        frame = graphPage(parent = container)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        
app = stock() 
app.mainloop()
```

The tkinter window just stays blank. It doesn't even display the label. The label is displayed when not using pyplot.figure. Turns out default interactive mode on jupyter notebook is False. When changed to true it opens a new window called Figure and plots the graph in it. Tkinter window still stays blank.

Edit: Using stock = tk.Tk() to define tkinter window fixes the issue. However, it is not feasible since I'll eventually have multiple pages which will be loaded into tkinter class as different frames

Comment: Specify the parent `self` in the line `container = tk.Frame()`, i.e. change to `container = tk.Frame(self)`.